# Is there any solution how to solve this scenario using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem solving this issue.

Type List

```
Road
Street
Bridge
Service Way
```

Scenario 1

Word = `Roadknight Street`

should match the world Street since only Street could match the whole word. and split into two since there is a matching word from the type list

Expected:

```
Roadknight
Street
```

Scenario 2

Word = `Road Train Road`

should match the last road only and split the word into two since there is a matching word from the type list

Expected:

```
Road Train
Road
```

Scenario 3

Word = `McBridge Service Way`

should match the Service Way and split the word into two since there is a matching word from the type list

Expected:

```
McBridge
Service Way
```

Is there any way that I can match starting from the right to left like the Road Train Road. I need to match from the right and stop once a match is available

So far I used match and some regex but didn't work.

To match the type list and get the Street Type like `Road`

```
const typeObj = types.find(type => word.match(type.name));
```

and this

```
const typeObj = types.find(type => word.includes(type.name));
```

but didn't work since it match even it not whole word like `Roadknight` it match `Road`

To get the street name like `Roadknight`

```
const name = word.replace(new RegExp(`\\b${type}\\b/gi`), '');
```

didn't work not sure why

and this

```
const name = word.replace(type, '');
```

didn't work since it replace all the matching types.

Hope anybody could help me this one

Comment: I don't understand why `Road Train Road` doesn't become _three_ lines instead of two.

Comment: So, `road monkey road` gives `road monkey`... Thinking about future enhancements, what about `avenue frog avenue`? `avenue frog` or `frog avenue`? Put simply, treating natural language processing as something solvable by regex is... misguided.

Comment: Yeah that's one of the scenario I'm facing right now too. Since I need to separate only 1 matching starting from the right. In real scenario `Road Train` is the street name and `Road` is the street type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For match try to use `endsWith`:

```js
const typeObj = types.find(type => word.endsWith(type.name));
```

And then for trimming use `substr`:

```js
const x = word.substr(0, word.length - typeObj.length)
```

Comment: I will try this mate :)

Comment: wohhhhh you save my day bro thank you so much

Comment: sorry bro I can't vote up this since I don't have 15 reputation :) but worth to vote up thanks for the answer :)